# I am going to work with laravel 5.6 and I get this error when installing composer, what can I do?

Tags: php, laravel, laragon

```
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\learning-final> composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
Verifying lock file contents can be installed on current platform.
Package operations: 36 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Downloading caouecs/laravel-lang (3.0.62)
 0/1 [>---------------------------]   0%    Failed to download caouecs/laravel-lang from dist: The "https://api.github.com/repos/caouecs/lang/zipball/fcb8cec051b175278e0a9efa440f0b1033d12dd7" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/2 404 )
    Now trying to download from source
 1/1 [============================] 100%

  [RuntimeException]
  git was not found in your PATH, skipping source download


install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-suggest] [--no-dev] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-install] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
```

Comment: The error is because downloading the package is giving 404, means the package is not found so the composer is looking for the source github repository, but you dont have git on your system, so your package has failed to download.

Comment: How can I solve this error so that the download continues and completes correctly?

Comment: First thing to do is to find out why the package can't be downloaded. If it was depublished, there may be reasons for it.

Comment: @eriktovaraguilar you can check for the package if it exists, else you can install git in your system. It will help you download your package from source repository.

Comment: Check if git is installed, then check your environment var PATH to ensure the path to git binary is already added. Then you can continue!

Comment: Have you solved this? If so post your solution please.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.
Delete from your `composer.json` the entri with `caouecs/laravel-lang`
And as instructed in [Laravel-lang](https://laravel-lang.github.io/lang/installation/composer.html)
Laravel 5.1-5.7 `composer require laravel-lang/lang:~3.0`
And try again with `composer install`